# Android drawerLayout: change navigationView to LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, drawer

Android `DrawerLayout` with NavigationView works. But replacing the `NavigationView` with a `LinearLayout` will not show its content. For example:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <!-- content here -->

    <LinearLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left">

      <TextView android:id="@+id/show_message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello this is a drawer" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The text message will not show. Is it possible to add all kinds of views to the drawer, not only menu items?

Comment: This absolutely is possible. In fact, the code you posted works just fine (I just tested it to make sure). There must be some other issue causing your `TextView` not to show. The only issue I noticed is that the `LinearLayout` does not have a background set, so the drawer won't look raised.

Comment: Setting background color works. Will font color automatically adapts to background color so that text are visible? Thanks.

Comment: No, the text color does not adapt to the background color. The text color should be whatever is set as the `textColor` in your theme. The default for the AppCompat theme is `#8A000000`. You can either set the text color in your theme, or just apply a text color to the `TextView` with `android:textColor="#000000"`.

Comment: android:theme="@style/AppTheme" is set in the manifest application element . How to set the a layout background to the current theme so that it is not hardcoded to a specific color? I think it should be automatically applied to all views. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand the question. You want to set the background for the window or for the drawer? Either way, it has to be a specific color, it is not dynamic.

Comment: For web, jQuery UI has theme which applies to all widgets. Wondering if android has similar theming.

Comment: Yes, Android has [styling and theming](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) (styling applies to the widget itself, while theming applies to the widget and it's children). So, for example, you could apply a style to your `LinearLayout` that applies a background to it. And you can set a theme to your `LinearLayout` that applies a specific look to all of its children.